# Which logical interpretation is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces

The question is:

Suppose $v_1,..., v_m$ is linearly independent in $V$ and $w \in V$. Show that
$v_1,..., v_m ,w$ is linearly independent if and only if $ w \not\in $ span($v_1,...,v_m$).

Should this be logically interpreted as $v_1,..., v_m$ L.I. $\land $ $v_1,..., v_m ,w$ L.I. $\land$ $w \in V$ $\iff$ $v_1,..., v_m$ L.I.  $\land$ $w \in V$ $\land$  $ w \not\in $ span($v_1,...,v_m$)

or

$v_1,..., v_m$ L.I. $\land $ $v_1,..., v_m ,w$ L.I. $\land$ $w \in V$ $\iff$ $ w \not\in $ span($v_1,...,v_m$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means\begin{multline}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\text{ linearly independent}\implies\\\implies\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,w\}\text{ linearly independent}\iff w\notin\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\bigr)\bigr).\end{multline}

Comment: I have already proved L.I. -> w. I am asking because I am not sure if I can use v1,...,vn L.I. for proving w -> L.I.

Comment: In this problem, it is assumed from the start that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$  is linearly independent.

Comment: Wouldn't that be interpreted as {v1,…,vn}  is linearly independent \land w not in the span? They are both true in that same instance? Which is what I have in my first answer.

Comment: I don't know what is it that you mean by \land. Anyway, you are supposed to *assume* that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent and to prove *under this assumption* that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,w\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $w\notin\operatorname{span}\bigl(\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}\bigr)$.

Comment: \land the logical 'and' symbol. My interpretation has the form (P and Q) iff (P and R) and yours has P if (Q iff R). These are equivalent when P is true if I am not mistaken. For my sake, I like to take conditional statements where the antecedent is true and think of them as 'and' statements since the truth tables are equivalent when P is true. To me this gives a better sense that two statements are simultaneously true rather than one follows from the other. But maybe that's just me.